# E0298 inherited member is not allowed

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to program chess. I want create is virtual parent class Tool, and child classes for each peace type. Here is my 4 files I writed:

**Tool.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Tool
{
protected:
    string type;
    int row;
    int colum;
    int player;
public:
    Tool(int row, int col, int player = 0);
    string getType();
    int getRow();
    int getColum();
    int getPlayer();
    bool isLegitimateMove(int row, int col);
    void move(int row, int col);
};
```

**Tool.cpp**

```
#include "Tool.h"

Tool::Tool(int x, int y , int p) :
    type("")
{
    row = x;
    colum = y;
    player = p;
}

int Tool::getColum() {
    return colum;
}

int Tool::getRow() {
    return row;
}

int Tool::getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

string Tool::getType() {
    return type;
}

void Tool::move(int newRow, int newColum) {
    row = newRow;
    colum = newColum;
}
```

**King.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Tool.h"
class King : public Tool {
};
```

**King.cpp**

```
#include "King.h"
#include <cstdlib>

bool King::isLegitimateMove(int a, int b) {
    return (abs(a - row) <= 1) and (abs(b - colum) <= 1);
}
```

But the VS don't give King to inherit from Tool and write the next errors:

```
E0298   inherited member is not allowed (King.cpp Line 4)
C2509   'isLegitimateMove': member function not declared in 'King' (King.cpp Line 4)
```

Can you help me fix this code? I have tyried read this manuals https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/  but it didn't help me.

Comment: geeksforgeeks is no manual. It should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: My best advice is not to use geekforgeeks to learn C++. Get a recent book at least covering C++11.  I've also found that learncpp is pretty decent. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-inheritance-in-c/.   And stop using `using namespace std;` Some explanation here : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/using-declarations-and-using-directives/

Comment: You *must* declare the functions you define in your class. Even if they have been declared in a parent class. `King::isLegitimateMove` is not the same function as `Tool::isLegitimateMove`

Comment: I added this decleration to King.h, and threre is still the C2509 error. The E0298 is solved

Comment: If you have a new problem, then please post a new question about it.

Comment: After I did build it solved thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in order to provide an *out of class* definition for a member function of a class, a declaration for that member function must be present inside the class. And since there is no such declaration inside the derived class `King`, we can't define it that way you did.

Thus to solve this add a declaration for the member function inside the derived class `King`:

```
class King : public Tool {
    bool isLegitimateMove(int row, int col); //declaration added 
};
```

Also you might want to make `isLegitimateMove` a **virtual member function** by adding the keyword `virtual` when declaring it in the base class.

Comment: I added this decleration to King.h, and threre is still the C2509 error. The E0298 is solved.

Comment: After I did build it solved thankyou for the help